# Displaying List with HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Can i append my list with HttpResponseMessage?
for ex: I have this list of Approvers which i need to append with my response message.

```
List <string> Approvers = new List<string>();

foreach (ApproverEmployee item in SinglItem.ApproverList)
{
   Approvers.Add(item.FullName + " , " + item.DesignationName);
}
```

and then finally pass the list with my response message

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, "Request needs to be approved by following approvers: " + Approvers)
```

But this is not giving me the list. Do i have to convert the list into datatable and then pass it?
can't i fetch the list directly?

Comment: You are passing the response in string, you need to return json object `{message:request,data:list}`

Comment: @Justcode : suppose i am appending it with a string message for eg: 'message = "xyz" + Approvers;' and later append this message with HttpResponseMessage like i showed in the example above.

Comment: won't work, post your full controller, let me check how you are passing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would not concatenate your list to string you would get the result I think.

```
"string value" + lstHede
```

will call ToString method of lstHede. And it'll return variable's class name.

```
public static System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse<T> (this System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, T value);
```

You can code like this:

```
var result = "Request needs to be approved by following approvers: ";
foreach (ApproverEmployee item in SinglItem.ApproverList) {
   result += item.FullName + " , " + item.DesignationName;
}
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok,  result);
```

Comment: You can use StringBuilder to create approver list. This will produce better performance.

Comment: Thats really helpful bro.. can you please upvote my question?